# How to install the Futura font in TeX Live 2010 in Linux(Ubuntu 10.10)?

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

How to install the Futura font in TeX Live 2010 in Linux(Ubuntu 10.10)?

Comment: If you mean installing some fonts in ubuntu and using in TeXLive, there is a simple way to access them. create a folder in your `home` folder name it `.fonts`(a DOT before the fonts), then copy your fonts to it then open a terminal and type `fc-cache`.
Now you have access to those font in any program and TeXLive.

Comment: Do you actually have the font files?

Comment: @hassan: this is true only for XeTeX, not for pdfTeX. It won't work with LuaTeX either, since luaotfload doesn't support Type 1 fonts.

Comment: tex gyre adventure looks a bit like futura: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}`

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on rvf0068's answer, first get [pfu.zip from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/pfu.zip) and unzip it inside `~/texmf`. If you don't have a `texmf` folder inside `~` then create one.

You then need the font files. You may have these from Adobe or from Linotype, and the instructions are slightly different.

For fonts from Adobe, copy the `.pfb` files into `~/texmf/fonts/afm/adobe/futura`, and rename them:

```
fub_____.pfb => pfub8a.pfb   
fubo____.pfb => pfubo8a.pfb  
ful_____.pfb => pful8a.pfb   
fulo____.pfb => pfulo8a.pfb  
fuw_____.pfb => pfuk8a.pfb   
fuwo____.pfb => pfuko8a.pfb  
fucb____.pfb => pfub8ac.pfb  
fucbo___.pfb => pfubo8ac.pfb
```

Copy the `.afm` files into `texmf/fonts/afm/adobe/futura`, and rename in the same way.

On the other hand, for fonts from Linotype copy the `.pfb` files to `~/texmf/fonts/type1/linotype/futura`, and rename:

```
lte50150.pfb => lful8a.pfb    
lte50151.pfb => lfulo8a.pfb   
lte50152.pfb => lfuk8a.pfb    
lte50153.pfb => lfuko8a.pfb   
lte50154.pfb => lfub8a.pfb    
lte50155.pfb => lfubo8a.pfb   
lte50196.pfb => lfub8ac.pfb   
lte50197.pfb => lfubo8ac.pfb
```

Copy the `.afm` files to `~/texmf/fonts/afm/linotype/futura` and rename similarly.

In both cases, you almost certainly will not have the full folder structure inside `~`: create what you don't have.

You then need to run `updmap` to make TeX aware of the font files. Again, the instruction needed depends on the source of the font files. For the Adobe ones:

```
updmap --enable Map pfu.map
```

or for the Linotype ones:

```
updmap --enable Map pfu-LT.map
```

(This is done at the Terminal.)

Comment: I think you need to run updmap as mentioned in `pfu.txt` : `updmap --enable Map pfu.map` for Adobe fonts, `updmap --enable Map pfu-LT.map` for LinoType fonts.

Comment: @mpg: oops, I missed that. I'll edit the answer to add it in.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/. Futura is pfu.

From pfu.txt in that directory:

"This bundle includes all files required to use the "Adobe
Futura" Type1 fonts with LaTeX on the Un*x or PC platform."

Comment: @rvf0068: I'm not sure a simple directory listing is going to help install the fonts

Comment: OTOH, reading the rest of the `pfu.txt̀  in this directory should help, since in contains installation instructions. One might add that `~/texmf` should be used as the `texmf` directory mentioned in this file (it may need to be created), and that the installation instructions for teTeX work for TeX Live, except that running `texhash` isn't necessary if `~/texmf` was used.

Comment: please explain step by step because I could not. And yet, I did not find the files. pfb folder pfu.zip
ps: my TeXLive 2010 is installed in the
/usr/local/texlive/2010/

Comment: help me please /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/fonts

Comment: But Adobe Futura is a commercial font, so the .pfb files have to be purchased.

Comment: and .afm? avaliable in the pfu.zip package?